# haskell function to take list of integer or string and return a list of integer

Tags: list, function, haskell, integer, polymorphism

I have been trying to create a function in Haskell that takes a list of integers **or** strings as input. It then checks the first index and it is numerical value e.g. 0-9 returns [0] if it is string value returns [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN48y.png). I tried to use the function `elem` but got this error:

Ambiguous use of operator "elem" with "(==)"

My code is:
[image: Code]

*I am not looking for a solution which includes importing modules*

The code doesn't have to follow this structure; It could be different. Output that I am looking for:

**f "abcd efgh ijkl"** `returns` [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN48y.png)]

**f [1,2,3,4,5,6]** `returns` [0]

***Thanks!***

Comment: Please rework the formatting of this questions, and don't use screenshots of code – copy it instead. (You can use ctrl+k for turning pasted code into a codeblock.)

Comment: It is not entirely clear why you want to return a *list* of `Int`s, nor why you need an `Eq` typeconstraint here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a bit confused. Haskell doesn't do "I don't know what type that thing is".

However, if you want to write instead a function which can be cast to take a list of integers or cast to take a list of strings (contrast: "takes a list of integers or strings"), you may use a typeclass. For example:

```
class IsInteger a where isInteger :: proxy a -> Bool
instance IsInteger Char where isInteger _ = False
instance IsInteger Integer where isInteger _ = True
```

Try it out in ghci:

```
> isInteger "abcdefg"
False
> isInteger [0,1,2,3]
True
```